# Google Places API : Page Token Errors

Tags: google-places-api

I'm basically querying the google places API for stores in atlanta.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.7488,-84.3874&radius=50000&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&types=amusement_park|art_gallery|bakery|bar|beauty_salon|bicycle_store|book_store|bowling_alley|cafe|car_repair|car_wash|clothing_store|florist|furniture_store|gym|hair_care|home_goods_store|jewelry_store|laundry|liquor_store|museum|night_club|pet_store|pharmacy|restaurant|shoe_store|spa|store|veterinary_care|zoo
```

This as expected returns a result with a page token to get another page of data with the same query.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&page_token=PAGE_TOKEN_HERE
```

According to their API this second URL is all I need to get the 2nd page of data. But it ALWAYS returns "REQUEST_DENIED".

```
"{\n   \"html_attributions\" : [],\n   \"results\" : [],\n   \"status\" : \"REQUEST_DENIED\"\n}\n"
```

It's not clear WHY I'm getting request denied. I'm nowhere NEAR my daily limit. If I try to run the 2nd URL with ALL the given parameters from the first URL with the Token Included it acts as if I'm requesting the 1st page all over again and ignores the page_token entirely.

Has anybody gotten this page_token to work?!?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bug in the documentation and will be fixed asap. The correct parameter to use is `pagetoken` NOT `page_token`.

Comment: the same thing also for rankby parameter.According to docu it is rankby but it needs to be rankBy (Case sensitive)