# Google Places API : Next Page Token Errors

Tags: google-places-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Places API : Page Token Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367307/google-places-api-page-token-errors)

When trying to get the next page i get REQUEST_DENIED i tried following the answer given here:
[Google Places API : Page Token Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367307/google-places-api-page-token-errors)

and it was not helpful can some one tell me what am i doing wrong:

the first request is:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=32.12313,34.81649&radius=500&types&sensor=false&type=restaurant&key=MY_API_KEY

the request for the next page i tried and they all return the same result REQUEST_DENIED:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?key=MY_API_KEY&**page_token**=ClREAAAAuG1aiCCfHnOxAkikjB6KeX7X0frDUn-cicSo1dt4iPoVwJubPspSmIXCvx8TRj1rvYwrlFhOOo0sL2Qf1E_45Ns36cM0VEkOLn4uPHBKH28SEIIgbTu00cePSEUuLgiKTm8aFBa709qEWkpww6ya_v25dfbV-43N

and i tried to change **page_token** to **nextpage** and **next_page**

is there any limitation on a country or a geolocation? is this option to get next page even work

Comment: We are working to make the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) clearer, however you must always include the `key` and `sensor` parameter in all your requests to the Places API Web Service. It appears you are missing the `sensor` parameter.

Comment: i added the sensor as follow: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?nextpage=ClREAAAAdTvky2obQITIMAC_J11quH6AvQtsmeqI6Q8libC1THjD_XvLKskFc-iyFd-s0QQaZfLi8xsBpeOlhHaE_Q2PMJmLfC7gyopZL_qDQzUhmNkSEAIwg-6tmfxEyXzrJImANEgaFNpZ6F6aXRDpkVxwZIiFAE3z6zlc&sensor=false&key=MY_APP_KEY and now i get INVALID_rEQUEST

Comment: Sorry for the mix up, the correct parameter is `pagetoken`